# Как удалить не свои маркера из firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-android

В базу данных `firebase` приходят маркера от зарегистрированных пользователей и через определенное время я их удаляю:

```
DatabaseReference markerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Markers").child("Markers");
markerRef.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).orderByChild("timeStamp").endAt(cutoff).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
data.getRef().removeValue();
}}
    
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
throw databaseError.toException();
}
});
```

И они удаляются когда аккаунт в сети, а когда пользователь удаляет приложение или выходит из аккаунта, тогда маркера остаются в базе, как это исправить???

Comment: Удаляйте маркеры при бездействии пользователя в течение N дней

Comment: Это как? что то не понимаю

Comment: Firebase - облачная база данных. У вас, я считаю, должен быть доступ ко всем записям базы (хоть и ограниченный). Пускай каждый заходящий в приложение отмечается. Раз в день вы проверяете отметки, если отметок нет N дней, то удаляете записи пользователя. Для удобства можно создать свой adminApp

Comment: Как отмечать каждого заходящего в приложении? Где прочитать? Может примеры?

Comment: Проверить текущее состояние каждого пользователя?

Comment: Заносите новое значение в каждый вход пользователя. Если последняя запись пользователя была произведена позднее N дней, то удаляете все его метки. Организуйте свой adminApp

Comment: нифига не поняьно...Тогда Как сделать adminApp?

Comment: Разрешу себе последний комментарий. adminApp - приложение для вас. Реализуйте в нём автоматическую фильтрацию меток. Заходите раз в день - проверяете активность пользователей. В случае отсутствия активности отправляете запрос на удаление меток.

Answer (score 0):

Можно например добавить переменную lastseen которая будет содержать дату последнего входа.
Потом надо проверять все аккаунты на эту переменную и удалять аккаунты которые не соответствуют требованиям.

Погуглите AdminSDK и Firebase CloudFunctions

Код для удаления аккаунта по uid с помощью AdminSDK:

```
 admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
 .then(function() {
 console.log("Successfully deleted user");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
});
```